# How to implement Daterangepicker with Datatables?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datatables, daterangepicker

I need to use this date range picker with my datatables as per a business requirement. Although, a typical usage of my date range sorting and search can be seen here. https://jsfiddle.net/zy914ko6/

I need help with how to produce minimum and maximum values to have the implementation fit the required jQuery script to draw the table. FMI: I am using serverside ajax and json on my production. So far my tables are running and I do get a draw but it doesn't reflect the "effective date [3]" column.

My "somewhat" working application can be viewed here 
http://live.datatables.net/pexopupu/1/edit][1](http://live.datatables.net/pexopupu/1/edit)

The sample of the code i used for my daterangepicker is seen here:

```
var table_1 = $('table.display#tb_posts').DataTable({
   "processing": true,
   "serverSide": true,
   "ajax" : {
      "url" : "{{ route('posts.list') }}",
      "type" : "GET"
   },
   "columns": [
      {data: 'check', name:'id', className: 'text-center' },
      {data: 'DT_Row_Index', name:'DT_Row_Index', className: 'text-right' },
      {data: 'id', name: 'posts.id', className: 'text-right' },
      {data: 'title', name: 'posts.title'},
      {data: 'username', name: 'users.username'},
      {data: 'created_at', name: 'posts.created_at'},
   ],
   "autoWidth": true,
   "order": [[ 3, 'asc' ]],
   "sDom": "B<<'span8'f>r>t<<'col-sm-4'i><'col-sm-8'p>>",
   "pagination": true,
   "pagingType": "full_numbers"
});
//DateRangePicker
var startdate;
var enddate;
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
   locale: { format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' },
   ranges: {
      'All dates' : [moment().subtract(10, 'year'), moment().add(10, 'year')],
      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      '7 last days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      '30 last days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
   },
   "opens": "left",
   "applyClass": "btn-primary",
   "showDropdowns": true,
},
function (start, end, label) {
   var s = moment(start.toISOString());
   var e = moment(end.toISOString());
   startdate = s.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
   enddate = e.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
});
//Filter the datatable on the datepicker apply event
$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
   startdate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
   enddate = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
   if (startdate != undefined) {
      var coldate = aData[3].split("/");
      var d = new Date(coldate[2], coldate[1] - 1, coldate[1]);
      var date = moment(d.toISOString());
      date = date.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      dateMin = startdate.replace(/-/g, "");
      dateMax = enddate.replace(/-/g, "");
      date = date.replace(/-/g, "");
      if (dateMin == "" && date <= dateMax) {
         return true;
      } else if (dateMin == "" && date <= dateMax) {
         return true;
      } else if (dateMin <= date && "" == dateMax) {
         return true;
      } else if (dateMin <= date && date <= dateMax) {
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
});
table_1.draw()
});
```

Can you help me reach a solution... 
I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: After further investigation somehow its implemented in a dd-mm-yyyy format so it thinks the information in the "effective date[3]" column is in the above format. Doing a 'from date of' 01/01/2019  and a 'to date of' 01/04/2019 in my calendar sorts correctly when it needs to be read originally as mm-dd-yyyy format... In my code @http://live.datatables.net/pexopupu/1/edit you can see everything set up as mm-dd-yyyy but still somehow its implemented as dd-mm-yyyy.....

Comment: i think this might help you: https://www.daterangepicker.com/ You can select the daterangepicker of your choice and use it as in your application as you have done here.

Comment: I am using that.... the subjective is coding in the best practice in datatables implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Via assistance received from Datatables.net forum.](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/59486)

```
var startdate;
var enddate;

 $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
 function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
 if (typeof startdate === 'undefined' || typeof enddate === 'undefined') {
 return true;
  }
  var coldate = moment(aData[3], 'DD-MM-YYYY');
   console.log('coldate', coldate)

   var valid = true;

  if (coldate.isValid()) {
   if (enddate.isBefore(coldate)) {
    console.log('enddate before coldate', enddate)
    valid = false;
   }

  if (coldate.isBefore(startdate)) {
  console.log('coldate before startdate', startdate)
  valid = false;
 }
  } else {
  valid = false;
 }

 return valid;




 });


 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  var table;

  $.ajax({
  url: "table.json",
  dataType: "jsonp", // jsonp
  type: "POST",
  jsonpCallback: 'processFunction', // add this property
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (result, status, xhr) {
  table = $('#poview').DataTable({
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns([1]).every( function () {
         var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="custom-select custom-select-sm rowSort"><option value="">Trans Type</option></select>')
                .appendTo( $('#rowSort' ))
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();


                } );


            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' );
            } );

        });


      $('#poview_info').appendTo($('#sumInfo'));
      $('#poview_paginate').appendTo($('#pageInfo'));


    },
    "pagingType": "first_last_numbers",
    "scrollX": true,
    fixedHeader: true,
    fixedColumns: {
      leftColumns: 2
    },
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    sDom: 't<i><""p>',
    data: result,
    columns: [
        { data: 'policy number' },
        { data: 'transaction type' },
        { data: 'transaction date' },
        { data: 'transaction effective date' },
        { data: 'minimum premium amount' },
        { data: 'deferred premium amount' },
        { data: 'total written premium' },
        { data: null,
            className: "center actionItem",
                 defaultContent: '<button class="btn actionIcon" data-     toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1"><i class="fas fa-calculator"></i></button>'}
    ],
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: -1,

      className: 'dt-nowrap',
      className: 'dt-left'

    }],
    "pageLength": 5
  });

   $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
   locale: {  "format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
    "separator": " - ",
    "applyLabel": "Apply",
    "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
    "fromLabel": "From",
    "toLabel": "To",
    "firstDay": 1},

   "opens": "right",
   "startDate":startdate,
    },
   function (start, end, label) {

     console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') 
      +   ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label   + ')');
 });
  },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    console.log("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " +            xhr.statusText);
   }
   });




  $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
  startdate = moment(picker.startDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY');
  enddate = moment(picker.endDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY');

  table.draw();
  });

 });
```